# How to upload a mysql database from one centos server to another centos server over shh

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, centos

Anyone knows how to upload an mysql database from one server to another server over ssh?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to:

1. dump the DB on the server you want to transfer from
2. copy it over to the other server (using scp)
3. then ssh to the new server and import using mysql dbname < dumpfile.sql

Otherwise you can replace steps 2 and 3 with:

1. set up an ssh tunnel to the new server (see http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html)
2. import using mysql -hlocalhost:330x dbname < dumpfile.sql